# ASP.NET MVC4 The controller for path '/enquiry/' was not found or does not implement IController. error returned for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My application is returning this when I navigate into the Enquiry Area, I currently have to working Areas, Brochure and Enquiry and a third to follow (Pay), when I navigate to the Brochure Area the error is not displayed.

I have tried adding an areas parameter in the view where the error is being thrown, both leaving string blank and with Enquiry as shown below :

```
@Html.Action("DropDownList", "Enquiry Base", new { type = "titles", areas = ""})

@Html.Action("DropDownList", "Enquiry Base", new { type = "titles", areas = "Enquiry"})
```

neither of these have resolved the error.

Currently in order to display the dropdownlist I have a viewmodel, partial view and unity bootstrapper in the root:

**ItemsViewModel**

```
public class DropDownListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsViewModel
{
    private readonly List<DropDownListItem> _items;

    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            var allItems = _items.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = i.Value,
                    Text = i.Text
                });
            return DefaultItem.Concat(allItems);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultItem
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = "",
                    Text = Mui.please_select
                }, count: 1);
        }
    }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {

    }

    public ItemsViewModel(List<DropDownListItem> items, string selected)
    {
        _items = items;
        SelectedItem = selected;
    }
```

**DropDownPartial**

```
@using MBS.Exec.Mvc.ViewModels
@model ItemsViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.Items)
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IBrochureModel, MilitaryBrochureViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IBrochureModel, GeneralBrochureViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IBrochureModel, StandardBrochureViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IBrochureModel, StudentBrochureViewModel>();

        container.RegisterType<IEnquiryModel, MilitaryEnquiryViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IEnquiryModel, GeneralEnquiryViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IEnquiryModel, StandardEnquiryViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IEnquiryModel, StudentEnquiryViewModel>();

        container.RegisterType<IFormData, FormData>();
        container.RegisterType<IRESTExecutiveService, RESTExecutiveService>();

        return container;
    }
```

In order to use the dropdown in the area I created a DropDownList ActionResult in the EnquiryBaseController:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DropDownList(string type, string selected)
    {
        if (type == "titles")
        {
            var items = new ItemsViewModel(
                (from g in _service.GetTitles() select new DropDownListItem { Text = g.Value, Value = g.Value }).ToList(),
                selected);

            return PartialView("DropDownPartial", items);
        }
        else if (type == "leadSources")
        {
            var items = new ItemsViewModel(
                (from g in _service.GetLeadSources() select new DropDownListItem { Text = g.Value, Value = g.Value }).ToList(),
                selected);

            return PartialView("DropDownPartial", items);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I then use the @Html.Action code above to render the dropdown on the view.

Does anyone have any ideas why this error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
@Html.Action("DropDownList", "Enquiry Base", new { type = "titles", areas = ""})
```

you have a space in the controller name string.

Try this:

```
@Html.Action("DropDownList", "EnquiryBase", new { type = "titles", areas = ""})
```

I presume the reason the error goes '/enquiry/' is because it is only reading the first part of the string.

Comment: thanks, I made the mistake of presuming that the second value "Enquiry Base" was the route name not the controller, is now working

Comment: No problem. It's always ("actionName", "controllerName",...) then other overloads.